# Can't create a new file on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

For some reason, my ability to create files through Windows Explorer seems to have gone away. When I click on the NEW menu item, the only item is "New Folder". I attached a screen shot below.It happens regardless of the folder I'm in. I do have full access rights. I can open notepad and save a file anywhere just fine. It just seems to be gone from the Windows 10 Explorer. Does anyone have any ideas on how to restore this?

[image]

Comment: This happens if you are not an administrator, because TRUSTED INSTALLER becomes owner of all files and folders on the drive Windows is installed to. In order to create files, either become administrator or ask someone with administrator rights to alter the permissions.